# counting users from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count

I am attempting to count the amount of users with a certain team_id allocated to them.
at present we have a users table and a teams table, our users table has a `belongs_to` our teams table and the teams table has many-to-many relationship with the user.

I have the following code in my teams_helper

```
def number_of_players(team)
  User.count("team_id", :conditions => team_id= :team)
end
```

And I am calling this in my view:

```
%td= number_of_players(team.id)
```

The problem I'm having is that is isn't counting correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
# if team is an integer
def number_of_players(team)
  User.where(:team_id => team).count
end
```

Or

```
# if team is an instance of Team and `has_many :users`
def number_of_players(team)
  team.users.count
end
```